# What rendering APIs are supported by Blender 4.0?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu

I am wondering what are the rendering APIs (Vulcan, openGl, OpenCl...) Supported for GPU rendering in Blender?

Comment: You sure about that Blender Internal render engine tag? That's the old scanline engine that was removed from Blender 5 years ago. You mean perhaps Eevee? Or you want to know only about Cycles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cycles GPU rendering uses either "*either CUDA, OptiX, HIP, oneAPI, or Metal*", depending on the available hardware.

> Source: [Cycles > GPU Rendering — Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html#supported-hardware)

Eevee uses OpenGL.

> Source: [EEVEE > Introduction — Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/eevee/introduction.html)